# Hibernate question - map ArrayList

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, arraylist

I m wondering how can i map a class having arrayList which should keep its values to another table. Let take some code for example.

```
Class Person
{
int id;
String name;
ArrayList<String> childNames

}
```

in db has 2 tables
1. Person -> storing id and name
2. Childs -> storing child name and id
//pseudo 
    Object A

```
id;
name Ivan
ArrayList childs = new ArrayList();
childs.add("Peter");
Chidls.add("Lora");
```

so in db it shoud looks like

```
Table Person
id name 
1   Ivan

Table Childs
id    name
1     Peter
1     Lora
```

But using annotations, any suggestions?

Regards
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [@IndexColumn](http://www.codesmell.org/blog/2008/10/hibernate-and-indexcolumn/) annotation. Also prefer `List` interface over `ArrayList`, Hibernate uses some specific implementations of this interface.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz ,i will check it out.